# Could not open input file: drush.php

Tags: 8, drush

I have installed drush usnig composer by using following command in my windows 10 machine:

```
 composer global require drush/drush
```

After that if I run below command in my drupal project folder using git bash, getting below result:

```
ak@LT123456 MINGW32 /c/wamp/www/myproject (master)
$ drush --version
Could not open input file: C:\\wamp\\www\\myproject\\drush.php

ak@LT123456 MINGW32 /c/wamp/www/myproject (master)
```

If I run drush status in cmd getting below result:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\ak>drush status
 PHP configuration      :  C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.ini
 PHP OS                 :  WINNT
 Drush script           :  C:/Users/ak/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php
 Drush version          :  8.1.15
 Drush temp directory   :  C:\Users\ak\AppData\Local\Temp
 Drush configuration    :
 Drush alias files      :
```

But why drush is not working inside my project folder?

My project folder having following files:

[image]

Comment: Where is drush.php? It seems like it's in `C:\Users\ak\drush.php`. You have to reference it by full path if you want to run drush from your project folder `C:\Users\ak\drush --version`, or add `C:\Users\ak` into your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: I have already added drush path in environment variable. `C:\Users\ak\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\drush\drush`

Comment: Weird! What happens if you reference that full path when running drush from your project folder?

Comment: how can I run drush command by refering full path? can you please show me an example.

Comment: looking at your screenshot, I think maybe `C:\Users\ak\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\drush\drush` in your PATH is wrong? There should be a `bin` folder in `C:\Users\ak\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor`. Inside the bin folder, there should be a drush executable. So if you add `C:\Users\ak\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin` to your PATH you should be able to call drush from anywhere. Similarly, if you just type `/c/users/ak/appdata/roaming/composer/vendor/bin/drush --version` this will perhaps call Drush using the full path. I assume you're using Cygwin?

Comment: I am also facing this issue tried drush command by refering full path but still drush is not working inside my project folder